# Use _guidGenerator on AggregatedRoot model

Tags: entity-framework, abp

I have an EF model like this:

```
public class Test : AuditedAggregateRoot<Guid>, IMultiTenant, IProcessibleType
{
    public IList<Test> EventHistory { get; set; }
    private readonly IGuidGenerator _guidGenerator;
    public Guid? TenantId { get; set; }

 public Status Status { get { return this._Status; } 
 set { 
     if(this._Status != value)
         {
           
                 this.AddEventHistory(EventType.StatusChange, $"Status updated from {this._Status} to {value}.", null);
             this._Status = value;
         }
     } }

 public void AddEventHistory(EventType eventType, string description)
 {
     var event = new Test(_guidGenerator.Create(), this.Id, eventType, description);
     this.EventHistory.Add(event);
 }
}
```

As you can see, I tried to use `_guidGenerator.Create()`, but this always returns a null exception; how can I use an ABP guid generator on an EF entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `AggregateRoot` should not have a reference to an `IGuidGenerator`.

Use a [`DomainService`](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/8.0/Domain-Services):

```cs
public class Test : AuditedAggregateRoot<Guid>, IMultiTenant, IProcessibleType
{
    public IList<Test> EventHistory { get; set; }
    public Guid? TenantId { get; set; }

    public Status Status
    {
        get { return this._Status; } 
        internal set { this._Status = value; }
    }
}

public class TestManager : DomainService
{
    public void UpdateStatus(Test test, Status status)
    {
        if (test.Status != status)
        {
            this.AddEventHistory(test, EventType.StatusChange, $"Status updated from {test.Status} to {status}.")
            test.Status = status;
        }
    }

    protected void AddEventHistory(Test test, EventType eventType, string description)
    {
        var event = new Test(GuidGenerator.Create(), test.Id, eventType, description);
        test.EventHistory.Add(event);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```cs
// test.Status = status;                  // Change this
_testManager.UpdateStatus(test, status);  // to this
```

Comment: What about if you want to call the AddEventHistory in the setter of the property status? How can you do that?

Comment: @Jesus You could directly reference `SimpleGuidGenerator.Instance`, but you should generally avoid that.

Comment: Since `AggregateRoot` is directly instantiated, you cannot property-inject and it is not appropriate to pass in its constructor based on Separation of Concerns.